# jquery simple two image carousel

Tags: jquery, slider, carousel

I'm looking for an extremely basic carousel functionality with jQuery.

It should:

Scroll between two images indefinitely
Scroll left - right every two or three seconds
Have no navigation/buttons/text

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/UWbrQ/172/

```
(function() {
var first = $('.item').first(),
    last = $('.item').last(),
    itemWidth = first.width(),
    carousel = $('.carousel');
carousel.prepend(last.clone()).append(first.clone());
carousel.width(itemWidth * $('.item').length);
carousel.css({left: -itemWidth});
$('.prev').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    carousel.animate({left: '+=' + itemWidth}, 300, function(){
        if(Math.abs(carousel.position().left) < 2) {
            carousel.css({left: -itemWidth * (carousel.children().length - 2)});
        }
    });
    return false;       
});
$('.next').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    carousel.animate({left: '-=' + itemWidth}, 300, function(){
        if(Math.abs(carousel.position().left + itemWidth * (carousel.children().length - 1)) < 2) {
            carousel.css({left: -itemWidth});
        }
    });
    return false;       
});
})();
```

But with automatic functionality, and doesn't need the prev/next buttons.

EDIT:  Found a good one here: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/2Kspn/
EDIT2:  Nvm, got it: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/2Kspn/1/

But it stops on the final slide..
TYIA

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `setTimeout` function of jQuery to call(trigger click) `next` every 2/3 secs.

```
setTimeout(function() {
      // Do something after 2 seconds
}, 2000);
```